# I want to show different different colors between two users, call in hold and call in silence in Audio visualizer

Tags: node.js

I  want to show different different colors between two users,  call in hold and call in silence in Audio visualizer.
I found "wavesurfer.js"  but in that it showing only one color for all.
Can you please help me how can i achieve my requirement

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "between two users" ? Could you show your code for better comprehension ?

Comment: Thanks TGrif,  Can you go through this url  please, "https://codepen.io/katspaugh/pen/ZQPaxB". You can understand easily. I want to show different colors for different users in wave form(audio visuvalizer)but in this example it shows only one color.

Comment: You can pass a parameter to the _waveColor_ proprety of WaveSurfer instance depending on the user.

Comment: From the metadata(database) I am getting an .mp3 file,  on what basis i can pass a parameter to waveColor property?

Comment: The basis is up to you. I can't answer that part of the problem. Again, what do you want to do exactly ?